# Python Popen Password Automation error - GetConsoleMode failed, LastError=|6| at PERL2EXE_STORAGE/Term/ReadKey.pm line 346, <STDIN> line 3

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I wrote a little automation that tries to complete an authentication form. that up and till now didn't require authentication. However when I do so I get the Error:
GetConsoleMode failed, LastError=|6| at PERL2EXE_STORAGE/Term/ReadKey.pm line 346,  line 3.

It seems like it's originating from the program I'm running as soon as the Password field appears.

Simplified code:

```
import subprocess
import time



proc = subprocess.Popen('command to run',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)


time.sleep(5)

print('WINDOWS')
proc.stdin.write('WINDOWS\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print('WORKGROUP')
proc.stdin.write('WORKGROUP\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print('Administrator')
proc.stdin.write('Administrator\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print('P@ssw0rd123\n')
proc.stdin.write('P@ssw0rd123\n')

proc.stdin.write('\n')
proc.stdin.close()


time.sleep(60)

print("EXIT")
```

Seems like the password field that blocks the printing of the password characters as the user enters them has an issue.

[Screenshot of Error as seen in automation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jynkx.png)